# Windows 2008 R2 Boot-from-SAN Migration Methods?

Tags: windows-server-2008, storage-area-network, migration, boot

We are running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise on a Cisco UCS B200 M3 blade server that is diskless. Currently, we are going through a EMC SAN lifecycle/upgrade. I need to perform this migration from the host and we are unable to leverage SAN based technologies for replication. What are my options to migrate from one SAN to another? I've attempted to ImageX the C: drive and redeploy the image. This failed. I also have tried Windows Server Backup & Restore, this successfully backed up and redeployed the C: drive. When I went to switch over the initiator in the Cisco UCS blade profile to the new SAN, the server would not boot. Is there follow up from this that I need to complete? Is there another method that I should be looking at that I am currently not considering? When trying to use software RAID1 mirroring native to the operating system. I don't fully understand the implications, can you help me understand the implications. If I convert the disk (C:) can I still boot from it after it's been migrated? See images. Thanks!

[image: backup and recovery]

[image: software mirroring]

Answer (score 1):

To clone a drive, we ultimately booted to a Oracle Enterprise Linux (RedHat) DVD, jumped out of the installer and used dd to copy the devices. This was a block by block copy between two storage arrays.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, we elected to use Storage Foundations from Symantec- they took the LUNs from the new system, created a mirror relationship with the old LUNs, and once they were in sync, dropped the old ones.